# StorageClient UploadObjectAsync periodically throws exception TaskwasCancelled

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Storage Client to upload the File.

However, it never uploads.
Suddenly this throwing exception always-TaskCanceledException.
 Even the CancellationTokenSource never cancelled.

```
IProgress<IUploadProgress> UploadProgress = new Progress<IUploadProgress>(OnUploadProgress);

using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(localpath))
{

    if (null != await StorageClient.UploadObjectAsync(bucketname, objectname, null, fileStream, null, CancellationTokenSource.Token, UploadProgress))
    { 
        result = true;
    }
}

private void OnUploadProgress(IUploadProgress googleProgress)
{
    case Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Failed:
    {
        //always come inside this...
        googleProgress.Exception is TaskCanceledException
    }

    break;
}
```

Comment: I followed this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/using-cloud-storage) with this the [UploadObjectAsync method](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient.html#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_StorageClient_UploadObjectAsync_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_IO_Stream_Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_UploadObjectOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_IProgress_Google_Apis_Upload_IUploadProgress__) and it worked for me. Please specify the steps you used that lead to this error.

Comment: As an aside, `UploadObjectAsync` will never return null. (I'd also recommend against the "Yoda" style comparisons of `if (null != x)` but that's even more of an aside.)

Comment: Your title states that the exception happens "periodically" but the body says it's *always* happening. Which of those is the case? It'll be much easier to help diagnose what's going on if we're clear on what you're observing.