# Upload files to Google cloud storage using c#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using the below sample code to upload the file into the Google cloud storage (Bucket). it is working properly when executed from my local machine. But is giving me the following exception when executed in the production environment.
Program code.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string bucketName = "bucketName";
            string sharedkeyFilePath = GetFilePath("privateKey.json");
            GoogleCredential credential = null;
            using (var jsonStream = new FileStream(sharedkeyFilePath, FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(jsonStream);
            }
            var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credential);
            string filetoUpload = GetFilePath("demo.txt");
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filetoUpload, FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                storageClient.UploadObject(bucketName, "demo.txt", "text/plain", fileStream);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("uploaded the file successfully");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    public static string GetFilePath(string filename)
    {
        return GetFilePath(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location, filename);
    }
    public static string GetFilePath(string path, string filename)
    {
        return path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\\")) + @"\" + filename;
    }
}
```

Exception Details:

```
`A task was canceled.
  at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadHelper.CheckFinalProgress()
   at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadHelper.Execute()
   at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadObject(Object destination, Stream source, UploadObjectOptions options, IProgress`1 progress)
   at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadObject(String bucket, String objectName, String contentType, Stream source, UploadObjectOptions options, IProgress`1 progress)
   at gcsUpload.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\Ganesh Deshmukh\Projects\GCS\gcsUpload\gcsUpload\Program.cs:line 49
Google.Cloud.Storage.V1`
```

Comment: This is interesting, as a similar question was asked very recently - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831013 - but this is something I haven't seen in our integration tests etc. Could you give more details about your production environment?

Comment: Jon Skeet- Issue is resolved. There was an issue with firewall settings

Comment: Wonderful. I'd probably suggest deleting this question as it's unlikely to help others... either that, or provide more details in the answer.

Comment: Jon Skeet - updated the details Thanks.

Comment: This question shouldn't be deleted, it actually helped me.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with firewall settings. Above code work properly.

Comment: What issue, what settings, which port.

Comment: maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ - Port 80 and 443 was blocked.