# How to upload files to google cloud storage from c# code uploaded on iis

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage, iis-7.5

I am working on a project where I need to pass a file to an external API from a signed url.

My code is as follows:

```
public void UploadFile(string localPath)
   {
       string objectName = null;
       string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Resource.GoogleSigningKey); //path to google cloud key
       var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(path);
       var storage = StorageClient.Create(credential);
       using (var f = File.OpenRead(localPath))
           {
               objectName = Path.GetFileName(localPath);
               storage.UploadObject(Resource.BucketName, objectName, null, f);
           }
   }
```

Here I am uploading the file to Google Cloud Storage to create the signed url

this code works perfectly on local machine, but when I upload it to IIS, I get an error as follows 
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 21X.XX.XXX.XXX:ZZZ"

The IIS version is 7.5.

Do I have to do some configuration settings on google cloud storage for production.

I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while sending the request. at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadHelper.CheckFinalProgress() at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadHelper.Execute() at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadObject(String bucket, String objectName, String contentType, Stream source, UploadObjectOptions options, IProgress`1 progress)
```

**Edit 1**
The same code works when I create a windows form application and execute it on the server. Except for

```
string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Resource.GoogleSigningKey);
```

I am using

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(path + @"\DataFiles\TestStorage.json");
```

**Edit 2**

The IIS server is configured in a proxy setting, does google cloud accessing need separate configuration for proxy settings

Please help

Thank you

Comment: can you catch Google.GoogleApiException and provide the exact error message it is throwing?

Comment: What is the credential `path`? Remember that IIS is not running as a user, it is running as a service. This means that the path must exist to services.

Comment: @JohnHanley: Its is a file in the AppData folder: "~/App_Data/XXXX.json", hence I am doing a Server.MapPath in the previous line.

Comment: The path `~/App_Data/XXXX.json` is not valid for a service. Specify a full path.

Comment: This is the error I am gettingAn error occurred while sending the request.
   at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadHelper.CheckFinalProgress()
   at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadHelper.Execute()
   at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClientImpl.UploadObject(String bucket, String objectName, String contentType, Stream source, UploadObjectOptions options, IProgress`1 progress)

Comment: Please edit the details into the question. Are you able to *fetch* anything from GCS? Are you sure your server is configured to allow outbound connections?

Comment: Updated, I tried the same on the server with a winform application, (code updated in the question), it works. So I think the server allows outbound connection.

Comment: Do you see a log of the connection attempt on Google Side? and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967800/upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage-using-c-sharp) is a similar case that the issue was the firewall rules so can you check on this.